# jar download not possible on OSX 11 (el Capitan)

Tags: java, macos, download, osx-elcapitan, restriction

I'm currently having some problem with a simple/stupid java executable on OSX 11.
We have 2 .jar, let them call jar1 and jar2.
jar1 can close itself and call jar2 to download jar1 updates.
jar2 just connect to a ftp server and download/overwrite jar1.

This is currently working on both Windows and OSX 9.
I can't test on OSX 10.
It returns a "null pointer exception" on OSX 11.

Are there some known issues about OSX 11 restriction that may stop the download?

Thanks for the help

Comment: The NullPointerException may help to understand what's going on: add it to your post. Which JRE/version are you using ?

Comment: On some macbook it uses JRE 6 (the .dmg you can download from apple official site) and some others uses 8.x (from oracle's site).
I found it was something on the network path not working correctly, like java doesn't like address in \\192.168.x.x\ way.